# Magmi Configurable Import - Simple Skus Sort Order

Tags: sorting, magmi, configurable-product, associated-sorting

Is there a way to define the sort order of the Simple products attached to a configurable when importing?

In my CSV file I have ordered them the way I want but in admin it just seems to have reorderd by ID.

Can anyone explain how I can do this?

My Import looks like this:
simples_skusP50-50,P75-75,P100-50,P100-100,P150-100,P150-150

but once imported into admin they appear in this order:
P100-100,P100-50,P150-100,,P150-150,P50-50,P75-75 (I think this is sorted by ID)

please help!

Comment: Are you referring to the sort order of the simple products on the configurable, OR the attribute option values displayed on the frontend? (size, color etc)

Comment: The sort order of the Simple Products

Comment: What is the benefit of sorting them on the backend?  You can click the column header to sort by that column, right?

Comment: I have customised the list.phtml so it displays simple products in a table under the configurable header, I want them to display in the order I imported or be able to use a sort order